# Android- Multiple Views not being displayed.(Only first view displays)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have searched a great deal and have not found a solution to my problem. When I create multiple views and try to add them to a LinearLayout only the first view (cake) displays.

Here is where I create and add the views.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_View);

    PlayAreaView cake = new PlayAreaView(SecondTestActivity.this, R.drawable.cake);
    views.add(cake);
    PlayAreaView bomb = new PlayAreaView(SecondTestActivity.this, R.drawable.bomb);
    views.add(bomb);
    PlayAreaView crown = new PlayAreaView(SecondTestActivity.this, R.drawable.crown);
    views.add(crown);
    PlayAreaView scissors = new PlayAreaView(SecondTestActivity.this, R.drawable.cut);
    views.add(scissors);
    PlayAreaView trash = new PlayAreaView(SecondTestActivity.this, R.drawable.bin_closed);
    views.add(trash);
    PlayAreaView key = new PlayAreaView(SecondTestActivity.this, R.drawable.bullet_key);
    views.add(key);

    LayoutParams params 
    = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for(View v : views){
        Log.v("created", "view created");
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(v);
    }
}
```

Here is my main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_View"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/image_View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

I can create a single view and be fine but I am unable to add multiple views the the LinearLayout. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104936/linearlayout-addview-doesnt-work-properly), there was another person with basically the same problem.  However, they were not declaring the orientation of their layout so it defaulted to horizontal.  In your layout you have explicitly declared horizontal.  Is this intended (for example to have the items show up side-by-side)?  If not, change the orientation to vertical and you should be good.

If you need them to show side-by-side, then I am not sure off the top of my head how to do that, but I would guess you need to declare each view as next to the view placed before it (e.g. using something like 'alignToRightOf'.  Again, this is just a stab-in-the-dark but it may get you going on a correct path.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. I did not fully understand how the Activity handled views. For me to draw multiple separate views I have to loop over each view that I add to an array and call an overridden draw method in the custom view. After I understood this I was able to create multiple views and add separate dragging functions on each view. Here's the code.

```
    public class ThirdTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_View);
    layout.addView(new MyCircles(this));
}

private class MyCircles extends View{

    private Context myContext;
    private ArrayList<MyCircle> circles = new ArrayList<MyCircle>();
    private int size = 10;

    public MyCircles(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myContext = context;
        addCircles();
    }

    private void addCircles(){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            circles.add(new MyCircle(myContext, R.drawable.skullcrossbones, i * 40, 50));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        for (View v : circles){
            v.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int mouseX = (int)event.getX();
        int mouseY = (int)event.getY();
        MyCircle image = null;
        for(MyCircle images : circles){
            //Log.v("image checked X: " + images.imageX + ", Y: " + images.imageY, "checked");
            // Is the event inside of this view?
            if(images.getImageRect().contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
            {
                image = images;
            }
        }
        if (image != null){
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                Log.v("touched down", "touched down  at X: " + mouseX + ", Y: " + mouseY);
                image.dragDistance = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
                bringToFront();
                isSelected();
                return true;
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                Log.v("move", "moving to X: " + mouseX + ", Y: " + mouseY);
                image.dragDistance.set(mouseX, mouseY);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        }   
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }       
}

private class MyCircle extends View{

    private int imageId;
    private Drawable image;
    private Context myContext;      
    private int size = 48;
    private int imageOffset = size/2;
    private int imageX;
    private int imageY;
    private Point dragDistance;

    public MyCircle(Context context, int id, int x, int y) {
        super(context);
        myContext = context;
        imageId = id;
        imageX = x;
        imageY = y;
        dragDistance = new Point(imageX + imageOffset, imageY + imageOffset);
    }

    public Rect getImageRect(){
        return image.getBounds();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Log.v("draw","drawn");
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        image = myContext.getResources().getDrawable(imageId);
        imageX = (dragDistance.x - imageOffset);
        imageY = (dragDistance.y - imageOffset);
        image.setBounds(imageX, imageY, imageX + size, imageY + size);
        image.draw(canvas);
    } 
      }
    }
```

This is written for Android version 2.1 API 7