# Addview does not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have this code:

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parametersLayout);

LayoutParams b = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView view = new TextView(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(b);
        view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        view.setText("test");
        linear.addView(view);
```

When I use this code I dont see my `TextView`.

The `LinearLayout` xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/parametersLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/parametersChoose"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
```

But if I run the code again I can see the new `TextView` I just added and the previous `TextView` aswell.

So the previous `TextView` suddenly becomes visible.

I use this logs:

```
Log.i("childs count", linear.getChildCount()+"");

        if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            Log.i("visbile", "yes");
        else
            Log.i("visbile", "no");
```

And on the first them I run the code above I get:

child count 1 and visibility to yes.

I also tried

```
linear.notify();
```

and it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinearLayout addView doesn't work properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104936/linearlayout-addview-doesnt-work-properly)

Comment: its adding but ot visible

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue with the code you posted. Looks like your `LinearLayout` is inside a `RelativeLayout`. Make sure there's nothing drawn on top of it that would hide the first child in the linear layout.